# Azure Monitoring Service API - Deployment Name parameter

Tags: azure, monitoring

I'm using Azure Monitoring Service API and need to pass DEPLOYTMENT NAME as a parameter to BuildVirtualMachineResourceId API method.

At the moment its not clear to me where/how to locate this piece of information so it can be passed to the method. Both cloud service name and vm name are easily available.

String vmResourceId = ResourceIdBuilder.BuildVirtualMachineResourceId(
CLOUD_SERVICE_NAME, DEPLOYMENT_NAME, VM_NAME);

Comment: Use Get-AzureDeployment Cmdlet that gives you the deployment name. msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495146.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Get-AzureDeployment Cmdlet that gives you the deployment name. More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495146.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try Deployment ID... should be available on your Azure portal under the "Dashboard" screen